# Laravel: Unable to use Carbon diffForHumans in blades

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string..
What I'm actually doing is call diffForHumans on a fetched date in blades.

```
<span>{{$data['date']->diffForHumans()}}</span>
```

Comment: `$data['date']` is clearly a string not an instance of `Carbon`. I can only assume that either you or Laravel implicitly converts the Carbon object to a string(probably using `__toString` somehwere).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data['date'])->diffForHumans() }}
```

As already mentioned your $data['date'] probably isn't an instance of Carbon already and therefore needs to be parsed. The above will resolve carbon, parse it and get the diff.

Comment: the problem however now is , the date and time is 2018-08-02 12:14:06.. but it is showing me 1 seconds ago .. what is the workaround now

Answer (score 0):

`<span>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->created_at)->diffForHumans() }}</span>`
the `$data->iffForHumans();` method only works in .PHP file if you add `use Carbon\Carbon;` 
**BUT** in .blade you must write full reference of carbon and parse if to string